# Laravel phpExcel Maatwebsite, config delimiter and enclosure not working

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export-to-csv, maatwebsite-excel

I' new with laravel, and im facing simple yet serious problem. I'm trying to export data to csv file with certain delimiter and enclosure by editing `vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/config/excel.php` on line 121 and 129. I've tried o change it so many times, do `composer update`, `config:clear`, `cache:clear`, restart the pc, clear browser cache, and it doesn't worked. Am I doin something wrong here?

Comment: Try 'php artisan config:cache'

Comment: Did you published the config file??? Try `php artisan vendor:publish` ...

Comment: @SarnodeepAgarwalla I've tried that too

Comment: `vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/config/excel.php` don't edit this file I think you need to edit `config/excel.php` ...